# SMS menu not working when I click on it

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to launch the sms application using the sms_mail layout from the menu but it not working. is there something missing with my intent or am I using the wrong coding?

**menu: details_option.xml**

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/sms"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_sms"
    android:title="Sms"/>
```

---

**src: DetailForm.java**

```
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.sms) {

            Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + telephone.getText()));
            }
    return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly correct. Just you are not launching the intent. It can be done as

```
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + telephone.getText()));
   **startActivity(smsIntent);**
```

and make sure you have the following permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: @user1985807 If it worked, then you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the tick mark on the left! :)